# How to write a powershell scrit to enable system protection over the domain to all users?

Tags: windows

In these days I'm trying to enable system protection on all the user machines on our domain, in here I am looking for enable the system protection @user logons, any help would be greately appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog contains solution for your problem . :)

[How To Enable System Protection On All User Machines on A Domain using Windows Powershell](http://madurad.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/how-to-enable-system-protection-on-all-user-machines-on-a-domain/)